# How to calculate nested SLA?

Tags: azure, math

Microsoft Azure offers SLA of 99.9% for [ExpressRoute](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/support/legal/sla/expressroute/v1_0/), if you connected via exchange or NSP. NSP, at the same time, offered 99.999% SLA for the circuit. What would be the combined SLA ?

99.9 * 99.999 = 99.89% or unavailability for 9 hours 38 minutes per year ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These failures are independent events. So, if I remember correctly, the probability of one of these events (e.g. your system being down) is: 1 - 0.999*0.99999 = .00101 or 0.101% Or, the probability of your system being available is 99.899%.

Answer (score 1):

yeah, thats the worst case scenario. each service SLA is individual.